# Auto Increment Number Beginning 08xx

Tags: microsoft-excel

I currently have a list of UK phone numbers which are in blocks of 10 and 100 (example below). What I need to be able to do is increment the main number to have a list of all numbers in a specific block.

Clicking and dragging the first number auto increments numbers beginning with 01, 02 and 03.

```
01xxx: 
01234567890
01234567891
01234567892
...
01234567899
```

However when doing 08xx and 09xx numbers it just repeats:

```
08xx:
08001234560
08001234561
08001234562
08001234560
08001234561
08001234562
```

I have tried adding the first 5 rows manually and then  dragging however it still just repeats.

Is there a way to format the numbers so these can also be auto incremented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be as simple as building an increment formula... If you start in A1 with 08001234560, A2 will read:

```
=A1+1
```

This formula can be copied down as far as you'd like. If you need the cells to reflect the actual values rather than the formula, you can select the entire column, copy it, and use Paste Values to replace the formula with the data.